# Is there moderator or not? Centering and unsignificant b

Tags: spss, centering, interaction

I am trying to check if the relationship between X and Y is a moderated by M. Here is my model:

Y = b0 + b1*X + b2*M + b3*X^2 + b4*X*M + b5*X^2*M

where X - independable variable, M - moderator, Y - dependable variable. All variables are continuous and normal.

QUESTION ONE.

After reading some tutorials I found out that variables should be centered. But there are several ways to do it and I don't know which one is right:

1. First center Y, X and M, then do X*M and X*X*M,
2. First do X*M, then center it, first do X*X*M, then center X*X*M. And then center Y, X, M.
3. There is no need to center the variables Y, X, M, X*M and X*X*M.

Which one is right?

QUESTION TWO.

Let's say I have this outputs: https://imageshack.com/i/p1np2e1Cp and https://imageshack.com/i/p9n1zuCDp. I am not sure if I should take nonsignificant b. Which one b coefficients I should take to the model?

1. 6.839, -1.749, -.551, .222, .241, -.035
2. 6.839
3. -.354, -1.159
4. maybe there is other variant?

QUESTION THREE

Let's say I have the same outputs: https://imageshack.com/i/p1np2e1Cp and https://imageshack.com/i/p9n1zuCDp.
I think M is a moderator because of the sigificant R squares, anova, and significant interactions in "excluded variables table". Or am i wrong?